# Uninstall packages apache php and MySQL

Tags: 15.04

First, sorry for my bad English.

I'm new to Ubuntu Linux, several attempts to install **apache**, **php** and **mysql** have been missed.

How to uninstall everything and just install again?

Comment: Follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP and post any specific problem you have. Just stating it fails without additional information is insufficient, leaves us guessing.

Comment: Please pick a supported release if you want our help ;)

Comment: Which version would you advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 is not supported anymore, it reach the end of life at February 4 2016.
Better update to a supported version like 15.10